# Reduce image size of multiple images via ssh

Tags: ssh, e-commerce, scaling

I have an e-commerce website I made for a client.

As with any e-commerce site, there are a lot of pictures.
About a hundred of these pictures were uploaded by me, provided by my client.
The other 400 were uploaded by client.

The problem is that the first set of images that my client provided me with were about 100kb each, which is not such a big deal. The second set of images, the ones my client uploaded, were about 5-9 MBs in size. Obviously I didn't see this until it was too late.

So my question is this: How can I reduce the image size of all those load-heavy images to something more around 100-200kb through ssh/commandline/php.

I'm also talking about re-scaling the images to something smaller (currently they are about 3700px x 5600px).

Please note: I don't need a solution to re-scale the images when they are being uploaded. 
I need a solution to re-scale the images that are already on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your server is a Unix, you can use imagemagick/convert tool:

 http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/imagemagick

You can also use PHP+GD, see: 

 http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php